# Python 3 encode error Google Translate API

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I'm trying to translate the contents of a text file encoded in UTF16-BE using the Google Translate API as explained on this site: https://ctrlq.org/code/19909-google-translate-api. I want the output file to be in the same encoding.

Here are a few snippets from my code:

```
...

import json
import urllib
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import urllib.parse

...

def googletranslate(sourceLang, targetLang, sourceText):
    url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" + 
    sourceLang + "&tl=" + targetLang + "&dt=t&q=" + 
    urllib.parse.quote_plus(sourceText)

    urld = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    jsonfile = urlopen(urld).read()
    h = json.loads(jsonfile)
    return h[0][0][0]

...

input = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('input.txt', 'r', encoding="utf_16_be")]
output = open('output.txt', 'w', encoding="utf_16_be")

...

for y in range(offset,offset+size):
    text = input[y]
    text = googletranslate('auto', '<desired language>', text)
    text.encode('utf_16_be')
    print("T: " + text)
    output.write(text + '\n')

...
```

However, when I try to run this, it works for most lines but eventually I'll get an error like this:

```
T: <translated text>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PATH\TO\translate.py", line 124, in googletranslate
    output.write(text + '\n')
  File "C:\PATH\TO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0259' in position 22: character maps to <undefined>
```

What can I do to prevent this error? It seems to print fine in the command prompt. It only gives me an error when trying to write to the output file. Should I choose a different encoding? Is UTF16-BE not sufficient for Google Translated text?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That depends on the target language. If your target language is Japanese, then no British UTF-16 is probably not suitable. You have to choose the encoding based on the target language.

Comment: Ah, so there wouldn't be any sort of universal encoding? I was sort of hoping to make this program as flexible as possible to support all languages. So I would have to encode it in different encodings for different languages  to make it work?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'll try.

Comment: I've left the program running for a minute or two, up until now it didn't crash. This is a good sign.

Comment: @snakecharmerb that did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is trying to encode the text as cp1252 (a standard Windows encoding) when it writes to the output file.  This would happen if no encoding parameter was passed to the `open` function - is it possible that this is the case in your real code, but not your example?

There are two possible solutions.

Pass an `encoding` parameter to `open`, and set the mode as `'w'` , as you appear to be doing in the example code, and pass a `str` to the file's `write` method.

```
with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding="utf_16_be") as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Open the file in `'wb'` mode, with no encoding parameter, and write encoded bytes to the file.

```
with open('output.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(text.encode('utf_16_be'))
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot!